I'm rewriting a 2019 oneshot and am up to 37,000 words already. Should I make them chapters or keep it as a long oneshot?
The oneshot I did in 2019 was about 10,000 words long, but when I read it back it was terrible. Not necessarily bad but the pacing, characters and everything was just wrong (With a lot of spelling mistakes). A new reader to the oneshot and I talked and I said I'd re-write it both for them and myself. So far I'm 37,000 words in and have about 35-40% left of the plot to write.
My question is if I should leave it as a massive oneshot, or cut it into separate sections and post it as chapters. I do have breaks in the story but I worry that the readers will take a break then find themselves lost on where they were last reading. Even if I personally have no issues reading that much in one go.
Some further details:

It’s being published on a fanfic website, completely free!

It’s a series of events: a main event happens to the main character and that night is the main focus of the story, then after that is how the MC processes and develops, including how the supporting cast can help the MC in both good and bad ways. It has breaks between different scenes: for example, the MC has been missing for hours but the reader is reading her having a good time, then cut to a different scene of the supporting cast freaking out unable to get in touch with her. Things like that. It also includes cuts to a week later giving a summary of how things have processed since, as the MC had experienced trauma and it’s the development of her recovery.

I’m not saying they wouldn’t come back, just that they might find themselves lost on were they were last reading, say if they were in the middle of the oneshot and came back to find the page refreshed; I just don’t want to inconvenience anyone in that way. And yes I have read a text without chapter or scene breaks that long before, but my story does have scene breaks.



Your question is lacking a lot of information that is necessary for us to answer your question. 1. In what format do you publish? Is this going to be a book or published on the web or something else? Do people pay to read or is your story free to read? 2. What kind of story is this that it doesn't automatically break down into scenes and chapters but seems to consist of only a single scene? 3. Why do you assume that readers will not come back to a story they liked after taking a break? 4. Have you ever read a text of that length without scene or chapter breaks?


It’s being published on a fanfic website, completely free! 2. It’s a series of events, a main event happens to the main character and that night is the main focus of the story, then after that is how the Mc processes and develops, including how the supporting cast can help the Mc in both good and bad ways. It has breaks between different scenes for example- the Mc has been missing for hours but the reader is reading her having a good time, then cut to a different scene of the supporting cast freaking out unable to get in touch with her. Things like that.
(1/3)


It also includes cuts to a week later giving a summary of how things have processed since, as the Mc had experienced trauma and it’s the development of her recovery. 3. I’m not saying they wouldn’t come back, just that they might find themselves lost on were they were last reading say if they were in the middle of the oneshot and came back to find the page refreshed, I just don’t want to inconvenience anyone in that way. And yes I have read a text without chapter or scene breaks that long before, but my story does have scene breaks. Sorry for not fully explaining it in the original text. (2/3)

According to jerichowriters.com short stories are between 1,500 and 7,500 words long, novelettes 7,500 to 19,000, and novellas 10,000 to 40,000. Now this is to be taken with a grain of salt as these are averages and in no way fixed on either end.
Keeping that in mind, you are on track of having a word count of about 50,000, which is even beyond the long novella count and teetering on the edge of being a full novel. I would say it's very uncommon for novels nowadays, even short ones, to come without any chapters or breaks at all.
You say you could cut this into chapters and release separately, or publish it all in one go, however, this is not mutually exclusive. You can add chapters as you normally would and still publish all at once. This would alleviate the issue of you expecting the reader to forget items in between reading sessions.
You overestimate the willingness of readers to read 50,000 words in one go. Some people will definitely be able, and eager, to do so, but likely the majority will not. There are plenty of people who read one chapter of no more than maybe 2,000 words every night before bed for example, happily completing their novels in up to a month or even more. Expecting them to read 50,000 words in one go would put unnecessary strain on them and likely alienate people who find this tedious. From personal experience: Most sites I've posted my writing on have a limit of about 3,000 words per post, as this is expected to be the average maximum a reader can fully comprehend in one go without losing detail.
Some people take longer to process certain scenes than others. They like to emerge themselves in a story and take it in one event at a time, and fully process that before continuing. This is exactly who the chapter is for, to give people an easily indicated time to break with minimal disruption, and give them a clear indicator as to where they can continue on their return.
That being said, you mention you will be posting your writing, so I'm assuming this is in an online format. This even more indicates the need for chapters as it is unlikely to have things like bookmarks which readers use to indicate where they left off.
TL;DR: Adding chapters will definitely help your story. Not adding them might turn people off wanting to read it.

Thank you so much for your comment. I find it interesting that most people read only 3000 words a night? I’ve grown up on fanfics for over 13 years now so I’ve found when it comes to fanfics, the longer the chapter the better.
Saying this though, while I and many other I know can read around 10,000 or more words a night, it’s still split into chapters of about 5,000 words.
The only other thing is that I doubt many people will be reading this, as I’ve only got about 4 people from the original 2019 oneshot interested in reading my new one (it wasn’t very popular back then) (1/2)

I’ll contact the people I know will want to read it and ask their opinion as well to see if they’d prefer it cut. The story does have breaks in it and cuts to different sections, those cuts are marked on the story for people to find. I feel my original explanation didn’t provide all the detail necessary for my question so I apologise for that but deeply appreciate the help! Thank you so much (2/2)

@Tootired I would give you some advice from the workplace that also applies here: write for the audience you want, not the audience you have. Surely any creator willing to put their work out there would love for more people to read it and appreciate their effort. The more accessible you make it, the higher the chance of that.
